# Point inside a square

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

> If a point is randomly chosen from a square, whose sides are equal to 1, find the probability that the point's distance from a side of the square is less than the distance of that point from the closest square diagonal.

I am not sure how to picture this at all, really confusing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Start by drawing a square with diagonals. Then start wondering: which points have equal distances in this context? Make an effort to picture these points.

Comment: I understand that the diagonals have the maximum distance of $\sqrt 2/2$ from a square side and that the points distance from the side needs to bee less than this. But I am not sure how to continue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
A point in the shaded areas above is closer to a side than a diagonal, with $AO$ and $BO$ bisecting $\angle CAB$ and $\angle ABC$ respectively, and $\triangle BOA$ repeated around the square because of symmetry. $O$ happens to be the incentre of $\triangle ABC$, and the inradius is
$$r=\frac{A(\triangle ABC)}s=\frac{1/4}{(\sqrt2+1)/2}=\frac{\sqrt2-1}2$$
The ratio $\frac{A(\triangle BOA)}{A(\triangle ABC)}=\frac{OD}{CD}$ then gives the desired probability:
$$\frac{OD}{CD}=\frac r{1/2}=\sqrt2-1=0.414213\dots$$

Comment: Okay, thanks.. can you just explain the part with the inradius a bit more? I am not sure what it actually is, or what $A(\triangle ABC)$ represents.

Comment: @ivana14 The inradius (you can check up Wikipedia for that) is the radius of the _incircle_ that is tangent to all three sides of the triangle. There is a well-known formula for the inradius, area divided by semiperimeter, and I use A(triangle) to denote the area of that triangle.

Comment: Oh, okay, now I get it.. I was just confused by the notation. Thanks