# Probability that a point is closer to a side than a diagonal

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory

So I have a rectangle in which a point is randomly chosen. One side is $a$ and the other is $b=a\sqrt3$. I am supposed to find the probability that a point is closer to a side than to the closest diagonal.

I have found the probability that the point is closer to $a$ (0.71) and to $b$ (0.24). Now I was wondering how I can put these two probabilities together to form the asked-for probability. Thanks

Comment: The probability that the point is closer to both a and b than it is to the diagonal is zero, so the two probabilities do not overlap at all.  However, your probabilities sound too high.

Comment: maybe I made an error while calculating.. so I should just leave these as two separate probabilities, since there is no way to calculate a general probability?

Comment: Paul is saying that the events {point is closest to $a$} and {point is closest to $b$} are mutually exclusive, so you can just add their probabilities. If your numbers were correct, the answer would be 0.24 + 0.71 = 0.95.

Comment: You should be able to break the rectangle into regions where a point is closer to each line and calculate the areas of the regions (think angle bisectors).

Comment: @Michael Burr that's how I got these probabilities actually

Comment: @Mike Earnest that's what I was thinking about doing, but I wasn't sure if it would be correct.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a very similar question involving a square instead of a $\sqrt3$ rectangle [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2277622/357390).

[image]

Points in the shaded area are closer to a side than a diagonal. The rectangle divides into four triangles, each containing one shaded triangle; the apexes of the shaded triangles are the incentres of the larger triangles they lie in.

Assuming that the shorter side is 1, the shaded triangles on the east and west have altitude (from the rectangle sides) $\frac1{2\sqrt3}$, so have a combined area of $\frac1{2\sqrt3}$ also. Those on the north and south have altitude $\frac{\sqrt3}2\tan15^\circ=\sqrt3-\frac32$ and combined area $\sqrt3(\sqrt3-\frac32)=3-\frac{3\sqrt3}2$. The shaded area is therefore $3-\frac{3\sqrt3}2\frac1{2\sqrt3}=\frac{9-4\sqrt3}3$. The rectangle's area is of course $\sqrt3$, so its shaded proportion – and therefore the probability a point inside it is closer to a side than a diagonal – is
$$\frac{9-4\sqrt3}{3\sqrt3}=\sqrt3-\frac43=0.398717\dots$$

Comment: why is there $\tan15$?

Comment: @ivana14 In the computation of the area of the north and south triangles together, I come across a triangle which I know has one angle of 15 degrees. The diagonal makes an angle of 30 degrees with the long side, and because of the incentre property I know the angle in the shaded triangle in question has to be half of 30.

Comment: yes, thank you. I finally found where I've been making a mistake all this time

Answer (score 3):

The red areas are of points closer to a side of the rectangle. Its area is the sum of the triangles, two acutangle and two obtusangle.

The two acutangle are each $1/3$ of the equilateral triangle having side $1$ and half diagonals. A diagonal is $\sqrt{3+1}=2$ so half diagonal is $1$ (that's why they are equilateral).

So the area of the two acutangle is $2\times \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{4}=\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{6}$

As their sides are the angle bisector of the $30°$ angle the two obtusangle have the vertex that is the incentre (centre of the inscribed circle) of the bigger triangle formed by the diagonals whose area is $\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{4}$ and whose perimeter is $2+\sqrt 3$.

The radius of the inscribed circle is $h=\dfrac{area}{half\,perimeter}=\dfrac{\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}}{\frac{2+\sqrt 3}{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}$

The two obtusangle triangle have an area $\sqrt{3}\times \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}=\dfrac{3}{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}$

Therefore the red area is $\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{6}+\dfrac{3}{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}=\dfrac{1}{3} \left(9-4 \sqrt{3}\right)$

The area of the rectangle is $\sqrt 3$ so the probability of getting a point closer to the sides of the rectangle is $p=\dfrac{\frac{1}{3} \left(9-4 \sqrt{3}\right)}{\sqrt 3}=\dfrac{1}{3} \left(3 \sqrt{3}-4\right)\approx 0.3987$

[image]

Comment: [+1] A very well detailed solution.